# Simular simular un takewhile() que devuelva una lista con una funcion lambda

Tags: python, lambda

Buenas necesito hacer como una especie de **takewhile()** pero con una función lambda
La cosa es que e conseguido esto:

```
tomar_mientras = lambda l, condicion: [] if l == [] else [l[0]] + tomar_mientras(l[1:],condicion) if l[0] == condicion else []
```

Pero claro eso no funciona, obviamente hay cosas que se me escapan y por mas que intento cambiar cosas no funciona

necesito por ejemplo que si yo le paso

```
tomar_mientras([1,2,3,4,5], lambda x: x < 5)
```

> me devuelva [1,2,3,4]

Answer (score 1):

Para ver mejor el error hay que separar el lambda en más lineas

```
lambda l, condicion: ([]
                      if l == []
                      else [l[0]] + tomar_mientras(l[1:],condicion)
                           if l[0] == condicion
                           else [])
```

Como `condicion` también es un lambda, cuando haces

```
l[0] == condicion
```

estas comparando si el primer elemento de `l` es igual al lambda y no si cumple la condición. Tendrías que invocar `condicion` de esta forma

```
condicion(l[0])
```

para que funcione correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que buscas es lo siguiente:

```py
tomar_mientras = lambda term, l: [] if list(l) == [] or not term(l[0]) else \
                                 [l[0]] + tomar_mientras(term, l[1:])
```

El takewhile está en cortocircuito, olvidaste eso.
Puedes comparar el funcionamiento de ambas, son iguales.